# Applying three different background colors to three divs with the same class using LESS

Tags: less

HI I am completely new to LESS.I need to do the following task,
Applying three different background colors to three divs with the same class using LESS

Comment: Anybody please answer it..

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question isn't really what SO is for. Please read the "Asking" section of the Help, especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Tldr: SO is great for getting help on specific code problems, but there are better places for learning the basics

Answer (score 0):

Check out CSS's sibling selectors. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Note that this is a general CSS feature, not something specific to LESS